# Foundation Top Navigation Bar: Increase Width

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, nav

I am using `Zurb Foundation` to make a navigation bar with the code below:

```
<div class="off-canvas-wrap full-height">
    <div class="inner-wrap full-height">
        <!---Top Bar for Large up-->
        <nav class="top-bar docs-bar show-for-large-up" data-topbar="">
            <section  class="top-bar-section">
                <ul>
                    <li class = "divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">TEST</a></li>
                    <li class = "divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">TEST</a></li>
                    <li class = "divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">TEST</a></li>
                    <li class = "divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">TEST</a></li>
                    <li class = "divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">TEST</a></li>
                    <li class = "divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">TEST</a></li>
                    <li class = "divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">TEST</a></li>
                    <li class = "divider"></li>
                </ul>
            </section> 
        </nav>

      <!--blah blah blah more code-->
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.full-height{
height: 100%;
}
.top-bar{
background: #053f73;
}

.divider{
border-right: solid 2px #065eaa !important;
}

nav.top-bar{
text-align: center;
}

section.top-bar-section {
display: inline-block;
}
```

The above results in the following `nav bar`:
[image]

I would like to keep the `nav elements` centered, but spread wider (i.e. the nav bar is currently `440px wide`, but I would like it to be evenly `spread/centered` across `1200px`). How can I accomplish this width change?

Comment: Please add your CSS to the question so we can help.

Comment: So, the problem is more the path if spreading it across the 1200px ?

Comment: If I hardcode the nav width to 1200px, the nav elements remain the same small size and are not centered. I don't want to hardcode the nav width, because I still want the nav bar to be responsive

Answer (score 0):

if this is a set number of elements, why don't you just set their width to a percent?

```
.top-bar-section ul{
    width:100%;
}
.top-bar-section ul li{
    width:14.43% /* 100/7 */
}
.top-bar-section ul li a{
    width:100%;
}
```